# How to make changes in Word document in collaboration with another person?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

When I send a Word document draft to my supervisor, it may take several days for him to respond. Meanwhile, I keep working on the draft, making changes to different parts of the document.

In a few days, when I get a version from supervisor I literally have two different documents.

What is the best and fastest way to implement the changes?

When I try to implement all his comments and changes in the newer version of the file this takes enormous amount of time - I need to find his change in the first file, find this place in the current version of the file, make the change. It is easy for couple changes, but if the are dozens of them, and considering that the file differs from the previous version, some time I spend the whole day implementing the changes. And when I'm done, I need to send the new draft, and the story repeats again and again.

Is there are a more efficient way to work together on the file?

Thank you

Comment: Word can merge two documents, much akin to how merge tools work for text files. Also I think since 2010 or so you can work on the same document at the same time, e.g. when it's placed on a network share. I think they expanded on that in recent versions to actually have collaborative editing of the same document for multiple users.

Comment: @Joey From my experience the merge tool in Word can combine, say, Chapter 1 and Chapter 2 from different files, so you can have them in a single file. My case is different, correct me if I'm wrong. As to the other option, yes, it does work if you open the file in a browser in Microsoft Word Online, otherwise only one person can make the changes. The browser version of the word is very limited in functionality.

Comment: Are you using all the Word version mentioned in your tags? If not, remove them, because your question is not specific to those versions. Replace with better tags like *merge* and *collaboration*. The office tag can go too.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would recommend is to enable "Track Changes" under the "Review" tab in Word. When this is enabled, edits made by different authors (as specified in the Word options) will be highlighted and can be searched easily using the "next change" option.

With "Track Changes" enabled, you should have an easier time when trying to merge manually. This is my preferred approach.

Using Windows combine function in my personal experience only do more harm than good. You can use the compare function though to get a general idea on the difference.